# how can I create WebView Flex project

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I'm very new to flex and want to develop window based browser application with flex project. Want to use at window only. Neither mobile or linux.

Application is very simple and will be including URL addressbar and go button.

Comment: Do you have a specific issue that needs to be solved?

Comment: What I want is just like http://www.lucentminds.com/archives/adobe-air-web-browser.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. what you are looking for is nothing more than an AIR application. It is Windows based application that one can install and can access internet. Rest, you have to code for the webpage rendering inside that.